# I am having trouble importing and reading .raw files in C++ in xCode

Tags: c++, xcode, io

I am teaching myself c++ and i was wondering how to import ".raw files", but it needs to be able to take a file name in a directory file in the computer and read it. I am not sure how to start the program so the user can type in the file name they wish to import and  have that read.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated. Just for the record, I'm using xCode for the IDE and their default compiler to run the program.

Comment: `man fopen`, `man fread`, `man fgets`, `man fclose`...

Comment: So you're just asking how to get user input in C++? you can use `std::cin` with `std::getline` or you can just have the user pass the filename as a command line argument...

Comment: How  would I write that?